# How to reset ALL Eclipse setttings (not only workspace)

Tags: eclipse

I have problems with certain setting e.g. Java content assist and Java formatter. The problem is that they persist even after

- creating new workspace (all projects are gone, seeing welcome screen)
- deleting .eclipse from user folder
- deleting whole eclipse folder and unzipping a new one

After starting a freshly downloaded eclipse i still see my specific settings in

- Content Assist
- Formatter
- (there might be others, don't know?)

I am not logged in "Eclipse User Storage". So how to get an Eclipse as it would be on very first install?

**Some Details as requested by howlger:**

I installed a fresh eclipse by unzipping "eclipse-jee-2021-06-R-win32-x86_64.zip".

Before starting it i removed :

from maven project folder

- .settings Folder
- .classpath file
- .project file

from workspace

- .metadata

Now starting eclipse.exe choosing the clean workspace on prompt.
Checking preferences:

- indeed my workspace setting like encoding is reset to cp1252
- but content assist still has my previously set "Auto activation triggers for Java" set to `.absd...`
- Content Assist "Favorites" contains my previous list
- Content Assist "Advanced" also contains old settings

In all of these cases i can press "restore defaults" and it will change. But i don't want to click through all preferences and reset them.

Comment: Those settings are in the metadata in each workspace, so a new workspace should have given you the defaults.

Comment: as i wrote - no this is not resetting e.g. my formatter setting. i still see my custom formatter available.

Comment: Well I don't get that when creating a new workspace. How, exactly, did you create the workspace? "Switch Workspace" has an option to copy the preferences

Comment: by choosing an empty directory at the beginning or by removing everything (incl. .metadata) from an existing workspace

Comment: How can this be reproduced? Please give an exact step-by-step instruction and tell which Eclipse IDE package, version you have (including the way you installed it), as there are several ways for the mentioned things you did. Be aware that the formatter settings can also be project specific (stored in the project's `.settings` folder).

Comment: Please use a fresh workspace containing the date e.g. via command line `-data <path>/workspace_2021-08-21` (never ever delete the `.metadata` folder) and use _File > New > Java Project_ instead of importing something and then tell whether _Window > Preferences: Oomph > Setup Tasks > Preference Recorder_ is enabled and tell also whether you still see the issue. The content assist triggers are stored in the workspace `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs` as `content_assist_autoactivation_triggers_java=...` (please focus on one setting only).